# Collections.sort does not sort my list of objects

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a list of objects by its id. Here is my code:

```
List<Employee> employee = getEmployeeList();
Collections.sort(employee, new Comparator<Employee>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
        return employee1.getEmployeeId().compareTo(employee2.getEmployeeId());
    }
});
```

But nothing happens after the sort, it still shows the original employee list. Am I doing something wrong? I've searched everywhere but they all just do this and it works for them. Here is a hard coded set of Employee Ids:

```
public class Employee{
    private String employeeId = "";
    private String employeeName = "";
    private String contactNbr = "";

    //getters and setters
}

List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setEmployeeId("A1B1");
empList.add(emp1);

Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setEmployeeId("A2B1");
empList.add(emp2);

Employee emp3 = new Employee();
emp3.setEmployeeId("A3B1");
empList.add(emp3);

Collections.sort(empList, new Comparator<Employee>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
        return employee1.getEmployeeId().compareTo(employee2.getEmployeeId());
    }
});
```

Comment: what type does getEmployeeId return? was the list already sorted to begin with.

Comment: Are you trying to create a copy of a list, with the copy being sorted and the original remaining the same? It looks like what you do here is sorting the original list.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @BevynQ employeeId is a String :)

Comment: @RussellZahniser I'm trying to sort the original, can I do that? Or do I have to have a different list for the sorted one?

Comment: What does `getEmployeeList()` do? I'm just wondering why you aren't just doing `Collections.sort(this.employees)` or something like that. If `getEmployeeList()` were, say, returning a copy of the list, then you would sort that copy and then toss it without touching the original.

Comment: @RussellZahniser The class where this is in is very big, and I have other methods that manipulate the said list. `getEmployeeList()` basically just gets the employee list set by other methods in the class. :)

Comment: have you tried debugging the comparator or putting some logging inside it? the code looks ok to me.

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you atleast give some of the employeeID in the employee List?

Comment: In your example, you're adding them to the list in the order they would be sorted as.

Answer (score 0):

Check the results of the employeeId compareTo method.

If it always returns 0, the sort will think all the elements are equal. Collections does a stable sort, so if all the elements are equal it will leave the order unchanged.

Comment: Hello, I just checked in debug. It returns a -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setEmployeeId("A2B1");
        empList.add(emp1);

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setEmployeeId("A1B1");
        empList.add(emp2);

        Employee emp3 = new Employee();
        emp3.setEmployeeId("A3B1");
        empList.add(emp3);

        Collections.sort(empList, new Comparator<Employee>(){

            public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
                return employee1.getEmployeeId().compareTo(employee2.getEmployeeId());
            }
        });


        Iterator i = empList.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(((Employee)i.next()).getEmployeeId());
        }


    }
}
class Employee{
    private String employeeId = "";
    private String employeeName = "";
    private String contactNbr = "";
    public String getContactNbr() {
        return contactNbr;
    }
    public void setContactNbr(String contactNbr) {
        this.contactNbr = contactNbr;
    }
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is printing correctly output:
A1B1
A2B1
A3B1

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the list in the sorted order that's why you are under the impression that your list is not getting the updated. As far as your source is concerned there is no issues you are doing it right. The issue is your input. You are giving the following input in the sorted order as follows.

```
emp1.setEmployeeId("A1B1");
empList.add(emp1);

emp1.setEmployeeId("A2B1");
empList.add(emp2);

emp1.setEmployeeId("A3B1");
empList.add(emp3);
```

Your output will be as below

```
Before sorting: [A1B1, A2B1, A3B1]
After sorting:  [A1B1, A2B1, A3B1]
```

Try modifying the source as below and check

```
emp1.setEmployeeId("A3B1");
empList.add(emp3);

emp1.setEmployeeId("A2B1");
empList.add(emp2);

emp1.setEmployeeId("A1B1");
empList.add(emp1);
```

You will get the result as below

```
Before sorting: [A3B1, A2B1, A1B1]
After sorting:  [A1B1, A2B1, A3B1]
```